# I am trying to use PTVS in visual studio, but cannot set python interpreter

Tags: python, visual-studio, ptvs

I am trying to use `PTVS in visual studio`, but cannot set `python interpreter`. I installed visual studio enterprise 2015 and installed python 3.5.2.

I opened python environment in visual studio, but I cannot find installed interpreter, even cannot click the '`+custom`' button.

Please let me know if someone experienced same issue and solved it.

Comment: refer this : https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/PTVS-Installation

Answer (score 0):

I have just reinstalled windows 10, python, and visual studio again. It works now. I have no clue why it did not work before.